# How to use VideoJS plugins with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, video.js

I am trying to use [videojs-offset](https://github.com/cladera/videojs-offset) plugin, with ReactJS.

But, it is showing me follwoing error -

> TypeError: this.player.offset is not a function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import "video.js/dist/video-js.css";
import videojs from 'video.js'
import videoJsContribHls from 'videojs-contrib-hls'
import offset from 'videojs-offset';

export default class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // instantiate Video.js
        this.player = videojs(this.videoNode, this.props, function onPlayerReady() {
            console.log('onPlayerReady', this);
            this.player.offset({
                start: 10,
                end: 300,
                restart_beginning: false //Should the video go to the beginning when it ends
          });
        });
        }

    // destroy player on unmount
    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.player) {
            this.player.dispose()
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div data-vjs-player>
                    <video ref={ node => this.videoNode = node } className="video-js"></video>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is a common issue while integrating ANY videojs plugin with reactJS.

Comment: I guess that issue is videojs parent instance. Videojs is not set as global variable so plugin registers self in different instance from where you use it.

Comment: @bigless even if I add `videojs.registerPlugin('offset',offset);` in componentDidMount() , it still has the same issue.

Comment: Ok. That was naive. Did you try also init through videojsOptions like {controls: false, plugins: offset: {start: 10, end: 300, restart_beginning: false} } ?

Comment: @bigless : this worked, thanks a ton! :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is solved with following change -

First, In VideoJS Options, the plugins should be initialized, like,

    `plugins: offset: {start: 10, end: 300, restart_beginning: false} }`

if your plugin does not have any parameters, you can initialize it like `plugin_name: {}`

Then, In componentDidMount() method, register the plugin like this -

```
componentDidMount() {
        videojs.registerPlugin('offset',offset);
        this.player = videojs(this.videoNode, this.props, function 
        onPlayerReady() {
            console.log('onPlayerReady', this);
        });}
```

This solution works for integrating ANY videojs plugin with react.

Comment: Dear @Vishwajeet please share some example.